# the address is a multiple of N bytes

Tags: alignment

A memory address is said to be N-byte aligned when N is a power of 2 and **the address is a multiple of N bytes.**

What does that mean when an address is a multiple of N bytes?
For a number like 4 we can say the multiple of number 4 are : 4,8,12,16,etc. but for address it doesn't make sense to me.

I think maybe 4-byte alignment means every four bytes considered a cycle, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

What this means is that the address is indeed a number, or at least number-like (old CPU's like the 8086 could use two numbers for a single pointer).

The more usual way to look at this is in binary: the last N bits of the address must be zero.